# ExtJS 2.0.2 not displaying data in grid locally but works on server

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs2

I am supporting an app written on ExtJS 2.0.2.  The app works fine on multiple servers.  However, when I bring the code down locally, data (from the GroupingStore) does not appear in the EditorGridPanel.

I've tried resetting the paths locally but no luck.
I've confirmed the PHP service is getting called and retrieving data.

The grid comes back with rows but no data.  Am I missing something silly here?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Did you checked your store of grid. Is data in store or not?

Comment: If you are only having the client code on your computer, but are calling a server for backend, you are possibly missing the Cross-Origin policy of your browser. The browser is calling the server and downloading the json because the HTTP header of that json could contain a flag that would allow you to use it from other servers, but since it does not find that header, it blocks access to the content.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue and you're right Mohit.  The data was not getting to the store.  After adding a loadexception listener on the store, I saw there was an "Undefined index:" in the PHP file attached to the store.  I added an extra check on the array on the variable the PHP script was looking for:
`$filter = array_key_exists('filter', $_REQUEST) ? $_REQUEST['filter'] : null;`

Once I placed that in the file, the store had data and thus the grid was able to load.  What's odd is that I guess the servers on bluehost must suppress these warnings so the store doesn't see them.  Thanks for the responses and I'm in good shape now.